# Adicionando evento de clique em um resultado do Twitter Typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead

Tenho o seguinte código js que prepara um campo de pesquisa usando o [Twitter Typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/):

```
var users = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('cname'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: 'application/controller/TypeaheadSeed.php?QUERY=%QUERY'
});
users.initialize();

$('#input-friend-list-publication').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true
}, {
    name: 'users',
    displayKey: 'cname',
    source: users.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        header: '<div class="tt-header">Meus amigos</div>',
        empty: [
            '<div class="empty-message">',
            '   Não foi possível encontrar resultados para essa pesquisa.',
            '</div>'
        ].join('\n'),
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile(
            '<div class="result-values" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" data-value="{{username}}">' +
            '    <img class="img-rounded" src="{{profilepicpath}}" alt="{{cname}}" title="{{cname}}" width="48" height="48" />' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-left: 10px">' +
            '    <div>{{cname}}</div>' +
            '</div>')
    }
});
```

Como eu pego o valor do atributo `data-value`? Até tentei uma solução usando a função `bind()` mas sem sucesso, veja ele abaixo.

```
$('#input-friend-list-publication').bind('typeahead:selected', function () {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

<sub>Obs: meu problema não está em pegar um valor de um atributo `data-`em si.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

O evento `typeahead:selected` não existe, o correto seria `typeahead:select`, para pegar o valor da array, use o segundo argumento (valor que é exibido no input):

```
$('#input-friend-list-publication').bind('typeahead:select', function (targetEvent, value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Para pegar o atributo `data-value` (eu não sei ao certo se é o mesmo valor do input), use `.parent()` do jQuery e com o seletor `.result-values` que equivale ao seu template:

```
 <div class="result-values" ...
```

Deve ficar algo como

```
$('#input-friend-list-publication').bind('typeahead:select', function (targetEvent, value) {
    var target = $(this).parent();
    console.log($(".result-values", target).attr("data-value"));
});
```

Ou usando o `.data`:

```
$('#input-friend-list-publication').bind('typeahead:select', function (targetEvent, value) {
    var target = $(this).parent();
    console.log($(".result-values", target).data("value"));
});
```

Os eventos suportados atualmente pelo `typeahead` são `typeahead:active`, `typeahead:idle`, `typeahead:open`, `typeahead:close`, `typeahead:change`, `typeahead:render`, `typeahead:select`, `typeahead:autocomplete`, `typeahead:cursorchange`, `typeahead:asyncrequest`, `typeahead:asynccancel` e `typeahead:asyncreceive`.

<sub>Documentação: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events</sub>